# What is queue attributes in dispatch_queue_create

Tags: ios, concurrency

In Apple's sample code, [AVCam-iOS: Using AVFoundation to Capture Images and Movies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/AVCam_AAPLCameraViewController_m.html), I notice this following line:

```
// Communicate with the session and other session objects on this queue.
self.sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create( "session queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL );
```

And I want to know what the second parameter is about and what other options do we have other than `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL`?

And what makes it confusing is that in other Apple documentation, it says that the second parameter is reserved and should be set to `NULL`. It seems either the documentation is out of date, can anyone explain what the second parameter is supposed to be?

> The dispatch_queue_create function takes two parameters: the queue name and a set of queue attributes. The queue attributes are reserved for future use and should be NULL. [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW3)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
dispatch_queue_t dispatch_queue_create(const char *label, dispatch_queue_attr_t attr);
```

> Queues are created with the dispatch_queue_create() function. Queues,
>   like all dispatch objects, are
>        reference counted and newly created queues have a reference count of one.
>
> The optional label argument is used to describe the purpose of the queue and is useful during debugging
>        and performance analysis. If a label is provided, it is copied.  By convention, clients should pass a
>        reverse DNS style label. For example:
>
> ```
> my_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.subsystem.taskXYZ", NULL);
> ```
>
> The attr argument specifies the type of queue to create and must be either DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL or
>        DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT.

From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_queue_create.3.html

Comment: If you specify NULL as the second parameter, then a serial queue is created. Here is the link for the https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1453030-dispatch_queue_create